# How to register IRepository to Repository to all objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have `IRepository` for a lot of classes `IRepository<User>`, `IRepository<Customer>`, etc..
Is it possible to register in unit like this but for all objects, or I have to write manually 100 registrations.

```cs
container.RegisterType<IRepository<User>, Repository<User>>()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't. You can register open generics too.

```cs
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

Unity will close the generics for you.

Comment: wow! Exactly what I need! Thank you, friend. In 3 minutes when it will be possible by stackoverflow rules I will apply your response

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Unity but in the Ninject world you only have to register a dependency once.